# Using scanf/printf while debugging , Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, scanf

While trying to use `printf`, it doesn't print line by line and when I tried `fflush` in *Eclipse*, the program stops at the `fflush` line with an error saying

Break at address "0x7ff92984cad0"with no debug information available, or outside of program code.
when trying to use `scanf` while debugging the code just skips it

```
#define indx 10

void N3(void)
{
    int arr[indx];
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < indx; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", (arr+i));
        sum = sum * 10 + arr[i];

    }

    for(i = 0; i < indx; i++)
    {
        int x = sum % 10;
        sum = sum % 10;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
}

int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
    N3();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's `indx` ?

Comment: oh, sry index is just a #define indx=10 
a pre defined number thats all

Comment: Then the problem is not in the code presented.

Comment: yeah mostly the problem is in something eclipse related , im new to eclipse so im trying to figure this out

Comment: The only eclipse related problem, is that it has this quirk with buffered output in the console for years now. I mean you have some other bug in your program in code you don't show.

Comment: btw, looks like you just have a breakpoint somewhere. Go to the breakpoints tab and make sure to clear these up.

Comment: the only thing i didnt add beside these are the # includes cause idk how to format them i can put some screenshots

Comment: There is no `main` for sure.

Comment: yeah the main is another file where the N3 function is called from

Comment: This should be here as well.

Comment: to avoid getting out of the point, i've added all the code in a single file but the problem still presists

Comment: What if you just hit "continue" at the point it is stopping?

Comment: to be clear with fflush it stops there, when i press continue the code continues but it still skips the scanf without waiting for me to enter anything, without fflush the code just skips the scanf line

Comment: I've added #include <stdio.h> to your code and no errors or warnings occurred.

Comment: did u try it in eclipse?